# bootstrap modal under background fade

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I'm creating a website for a course project to use modals so the user can add announcements, dates, and links. Right now my modal appears under a gray fade background. I've read through 3 other articles on this forum about this issue but none has fixed my issue yet. Here's my code along with an attached photo of the model when active.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Important Report</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class='form-horizontal' id = 'addItem'>
                             <div class='form-group'>
                               <label for='email'>New Item</label>
                               <input type='text' 
                                  id='newtext' 
                                  class='form-control'
                                  placeholder='type new text here' />
                             </div>
                             <div class='form-group'>
                               <label for='date'>Date</label>
                               <input type='dateTime' 
                                  id='date' 
                                  class='form-control' 
                                  placeholder='05/15/2016' />
                             </div>
                             <div class='form-group'>
                               <label for='link'>Item Link</label>
                               <input type='link' 
                                  id='link' 
                                  class='form-control' 
                                  placeholder='http://www.google.com' />
                             </div>
                        </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">add new item</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">new item</button>
```

[Here's a picture of the modal when active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri2ui.png)

This code is directly copied from the professors website, where it functions perfectly, to my own code where now it does not work. (Contacting the professor is not possible)

Comment: You have a lot of css classes that are most likely causing the grey fade.  can you post that as well please

Comment: your code work fine probably you have an css that make the modal under background fade https://jsfiddle.net/b18h2uw4/